# Installing imgkit in Python

Tags: windows, windows-10, python

I'm using Python with Spyder, and I've been trying to install imgkit in Windows 10 but haven't succeeded. I already saw many videos and tutorials teaching how to do it, but not for Python.
I did:

1. Downloaded the program from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html.
2. Installed the program.
3. Went to python (and did `pip install imgkit`); it worked.
4. Manually changed the "path":
   -> On Spyder > PYTHOPATH Admi > add new path > selected the folder where "wkhtmltoimage" application is.
5. List item
6. Restarted the kernel
7. Executed `import imgkit`.
   And then it keep saying "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I finally did to solve this, was got to Windows (10) > Control Panel > System and Security > System > click on "advance configuration of the system". Then add a 
Environment Variables as the path where the imgkit (say wkhtmltoimage and wkhtmltopdf) is installed.
Solved